# DQL and MAX function call as a CONCAT argument

Tags: doctrine-orm, dql, doctrine-query

I have a repository function having the following instructions:

```
$QB = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
$QB ->addSelect("CONCAT(dsub2.dagId, MAX(tsub2.executionDate))")
    ->from(TaskInstance::class, 'tsub2')
    ->join('tsub2.dag', 'dsub2')
    ->addGroupBy('dsub2.dagId')
    ;
```

Calling `$QB->getQuery()->getSQL();` or `$QB->getQuery()->getResult()` raises an error saying:

> Expected StateFieldPathExpression | string | InputParameter | FunctionsReturningStrings | AggregateExpression, got 'MAX'

Replacing the `addSelect` call entirely with the following snippet doesn't work either and raises the same error:

```
->addSelect(
    $QB->expr()->concat(
        'dsub2.dagId'
        , $QB->expr()->max('tsub2.executionDate')
    )
)
```

Do you have any idea of the proper way (or a workaround) to nest `MAX` function call as a `CONCAT` argument?

*Doctrine DBAL v2.6.3 ; Doctrine ORM v2.6.1*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had the same issue, and i think it's a Doctrine Bug on v2.6.1.
The tricks I found is more a workaround than a real solution :

You have to change

```
$QB->addSelect("CONCAT(dsub2.dagId, MAX(tsub2.executionDate))")
```

by

```
$QB->addSelect("CONCAT(dsub2.dagId, IF(true=true, MAX(tsub2.executionDate), ''))")
```

By inserting a IF (that includes the MAX), Doctrine will not "see" the MAX .

But... In the IF you need a condition and Doctrine doesn't like `IF(true, 1, 0)`, so the other trick is the if condition : `true=true`.